# Menu underline when user active on this section

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I made a menu fixed and sticky. Menu underline is looking like progress bar when the user on specific section. Progress bar works but i cannot place it exaclty under the menus. for example, when I hover mouse on first section (call data) progress bar loads, when I hover mouse on second section (source) then progress bar continues. It works but need to place it correct way

Can someone help me to correct this? Menu Progress bar will be under the sections.

[Here is my code on fiddle, kindly test with bigger screen](https://jsfiddle.net/albanmahmut/azbvpes8/1/)!

I did try to find on web but could not get any info

```css
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #42AC82;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu_progress {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  background: #42AC82;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
  <a href="#call-data">Call Data</a>
  <a href="#source">Source</a>
  <a href="#lead">Lead</a>
  <a href="#address">Address</a>
  <a href="#motivation">Motivation</a>
  <a href="#property">Property</a>
  <a href="#visit">Visit</a>
  <a href="#finish">Finish</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div id="menu_progress"></div>
</div>
```

```
 //menu progress bar
$('.nav a').mouseover(function() {
var x = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
$('#menu_progress').animate({ width: x });
});
```

Comment: Can you better explain what you want to achieve and what the problem is

Comment: @VincentChinner progress bar works but i cannot place it exaclty under the menus. for example, when I hover mouse on first section (call data) progress bar loads, when I hover mouse on second section (source) then progress bar continues. It works but need to place it correct way.

Comment: So you want the progress bar to be positioned at the bottom, below the text, with the same width as the menu item?

Comment: @VincentChinner yes, correct. I tried to do it but it starts from half of the page and cannot make it right, do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are lookin to achieve ? I have done the following changes, please view in large screen. Thanks

1. Changed `$(this).offset()` to `$(this).position().left` to take offset width relative to parent rather than the page.
2. Changed `$(this).width()` to `$(this).outerWidth()` so it takes width of the container including the padding.
3. Moved `<div id="menu_progress">` outside the `<div class="nav" id="myNav">`.

```js
//menu progress bar
$(".nav a").mouseover(function() {
  var x = $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth();
  $("#menu_progress").animate({
    width: x
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #42AC82;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu_progress {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  background: #42AC82;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
  <a href="#call-data">Call Data</a>
  <a href="#source">Source</a>
  <a href="#lead">Lead</a>
  <a href="#address">Address</a>
  <a href="#motivation">Motivation</a>
  <a href="#property">Property</a>
  <a href="#visit">Visit</a>
  <a href="#finish">Finish</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="menu_progress"></div>
```

Comment: looks correct when I run on stackoverflow with fullscreen but not with my editor. May I ask what code did you add and replace? Thank you by the way

Comment: In JavaScript I changed `$(this).width()` to `$(this).outerWidth()` and in HTML i moved #menu_progress div outside the myNav div

Comment: yes but this is how it looks when I hover mouse on first section (call data). i added your code, so this should work right? on stackoverfow works. [image] (https://imgur.com/a/Uot2M50)!

Comment: Code only answers are not useful.  Please indicate what you've done / changed, why it works, etc.

Comment: @can i think the problem is that you're navbar is in center of the page instead of left aligned that i assumed. Hence the offsetwidth value is greater (because of the margin on the left of navbar) which makes the width of the progress bar greater that what we need. I have updated my answer and changed `$(this).ofset()` to `$(this).position().left` so that now it takes offset width from relative to its parent rather than the page itself. Can you test if this works now ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the code to reset the progress when you leave the menu and stop continuously animating after you've hovered quickly over the menu items.

```js
//menu progress bar
$(".nav a").mouseover(function() {
  $("#menu_progress").stop();    
  var x = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
  $("#menu_progress").animate({
    width: x
  });
});

$(".nav").mouseout(function() {
  $("#menu_progress").stop(); 
  $("#menu_progress").animate({width: 0});
});
```

```css
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #42AC82;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu_progress {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  background: #42AC82;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: -moz-sticky;
  /* firefox */
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
  <a href="#call-data">Call Data</a>
  <a href="#source">Source</a>
  <a href="#lead">Lead</a>
  <a href="#address">Address</a>
  <a href="#motivation">Motivation</a>
  <a href="#property">Property</a>
  <a href="#visit">Visit</a>
  <a href="#finish">Finish</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="menu_progress"></div>
```

Comment: thank you but this was not i was looking for. can you edit the way i ask or? looks good solution.

Comment: I've adjusted. Better now?